# CFC caching issue in Railo

Tags: caching, cfc, railo, cfml

I'm having a problem with a specific function in a CFC being cached, no matter what I do.

Here's the scenario:

The CFC is instantiated in the Application scope, via ColdSpring. The site is live and all is well.
I wanted to make a change to one of the functions, called 'productSearch' within this CFC.
No matter what I do, no change is respected, ever.

I usually restart the application to reinstantiate the CFC, but this has made no difference.
I've tried creating a test page and explicitly instantiating the CFC locally, but it makes no difference.
I've restarted Railo, restarted Tomcat, restarted the *server*, to no avail.

In fact, the *only* time that I can see the change I've made, is if I literally *rename* the function. The fact that this works suggests that the CFC file itself is not being cached, otherwise the newly named function would not be available.

What's more, this only happens on the production server. If I make the exact same change on my dev server, everything works as expected.

I've never seen this before and I'm at a bit of a loss. 
I really don't have much code to show that would be of any use - for testing, the function now contains the following:

```
<cffunction name="productSearch" access="public">
<cfdump var="#CGI#">
<cfabort>
</cffunction>
```

This fails, but if I rename it to 'productSearch2' it works correctly. For clarification, when I say 'fails' I mean runs the function as if it hadn't changed at all - there was all manner of logic in it before, returning a struct.

Does Railo store a parsed version of CFCs anywhere or something? I just can't see how this is happening!

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but check your `WEB-INF/railo/cfclasses` directory - somewhere within there will be the .class file that is generated for the CFC - check if that is being re-generated?

Comment: You'll get a quicker answer if you ask this on the Railo Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/railo

Comment: Peter - Thanks! I looked in there and it *was* being recreated, but so was another file that lead me in the right direction. Answer below.

Adam - I wasn't too sure this was specific to Railo, I couldn't recreate on my dev Railo server, so not much point trying to test ACF. Having now found the answer, I think it *may* be Railo specific, as I'm pretty sure I'd have come across this in the past if ACF exhibited the behaviour.

Comment: Actually, having just started typing out my answer - I think I may have stumbled across the problem and it specific neither to Railo, nor ACF - but in fact, as is so often the case, my code. Oh dear.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this issue was down to a methodology I'm using in my code...

I split my components down into manageable `.cfm` files, which I then include using `DirectoryList` and `CFInclude` from inside a base `.cfc` file

This works very well for me, however in this instance, a recent merge of dev and live versions of the file in question left me with a `.orig` file - and as my files are included using `DirectoryList`, it seems the `.orig` was being included in the component after the `.cfm` version was loaded - thus overwriting any functions that exist within both files. This is why renaming the function worked!

Comment: You've now added a filter of `*.cfm` to the [DirectoryList](http://railodocs.org/directorylist) call, right?

Comment: Indeed... Previously I was filtering *out* `*.cfc` - I should have known that would cause problems!